# IAM or AD in azure

Tags: azure

In azure cloud i want to create two users. Both the users will not able to watch , manage others resources like user1 created a VM and user2 also create another VM so user2 should not able to watch or start,stop, terminate user1 resources what ever resource user1 using. As a whole user can manage and view only his resources not others

Answer (score 1):

You can create a resource group for each user.
Then give them Contributor role to their resource group.
They will then be able to only see/create/modify things in their resource group and nothing else.
So user 1 can't see user 2's resources and vice versa.

Though if they have roles at subscription-level then they will have those rights across all resource groups.
So if you don't want that, remove their subscription-level roles.

Comment: I am new to azure can you please describe the solution step by step. Like how to assign Contributor role to their resource group. Please help .

Comment: After creating a resource group, there should be a Access control (IAM) tab. There you can add role assignments. It's quite straightforward once you find it, select a role and select the user.